# How to add widgets positioned relative to a tab in a QTabBar?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to add some widgets to a `QTabBar`? I wanted to have a `QComboBox` to the side of the last tab, and have it only appear when the last tab is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to add child overlay widgets to any widget, so the answer is: sure!

You can hook to the tab widgets's or tab bar's signals to get notified when the last tab is selected. Then use `tabRect()` to get the rectangle of the last tab. Position your combo box to the right of it. It'd need to be a child of the tab bar. That's it.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in Qt Designer?

Comment: @mFeinstein: No, you have to write some code for this. In the long run I find Qt Designer to be a hindrance more than help. It confuses the heck out of newbies who don't realize that widgets can be easily composed programmatically.

Comment: @mFeinstein Anyway, to use your widget you have to write some code anyway, so Qt Designer not letting you do it is of no consequence.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to speed things up..one thing I find annoying in Qt Designer (probably Qt in general) is to deal with layouts, the form editor of visual studio makes stuff a lot easier with ancors and aligments...

Comment: @mFeinstein QML has it all.

Comment: Yes, QML is my next step! I just wonder if it has some performance impacts, I always saw c++ as a language more prone to be real time, but with so many top level stuff, maybe there could be some impact in the performance?

Comment: @mFeinstein: QML in Qt 5.2 generally performs very well. In cases where you don't write javascript code, QML has next to no runtime impact. QML is used to instantiate a bunch of objects when your scene is set up. That's it. It doesn't matter afterwards.

Comment: interesting, I will take a look on it!

Comment: @mFeinstein QML is all written in C++, and once your qml file has been parsed all that's left is a bunch of data structures in memory. They are all processed by C++ code.

Comment: Also, don't confuse QML with Qt Quick 2. QML is an engine that takes a qml file, and instantiates QObjects (such as QQuickItem and derivatives) per your instructions. It also runs when bindings are updated, but that's often very trivial code. Qt Quick 2 is the GUI framework built on top of QML. Qt Quick 1 is another such framework (an entirely separate implementation).

Comment: Ouch, that's a trap for newbies...can you elaborate more on the difference? Is it like Qt Quick has stuff made of QML? What's the differences/advantages/cons of using it?

Comment: @mFeinstein QML is to Qt Quick 2 is like Qt Core module is to Qt Gui module. The latter is implemented on top of the former. QML doesn't know anything about graphics. It's an execution engine that instantiates objects, manages bindings between objects, and lets you script things in javascript. Qt Quick 1 and Qt Quick 2 are two separate GUI technologies built on top of QML.

Comment: Got it! So to make things real easy I should design a GUI in Qt Quick 2...and it will create for me, behind the scenes, all the QML code needed, right?

Comment: @mFeinstein Almost. When you build anything using Qt Quick 1 or 2, you use QML to express yourself :)

Comment: I thoght it was like a graphical interface for automatically building the QML, I guess I will get the feeling when I start playing with it...is it correct to assume Qt Quick 2 is better than Qt Quick 1 or the numbers have no meaning?

Comment: @mFeinstein Qt Quick 2 is better in the sense that it uses the GPU to do all of the rendering. Whatever GUI is used to create the QML code is irrelevant to this discussion.

Answer (score -1):

It might be easier to use a QStackedWidget to get your desired results.  When you are using the QStackedWidget you can have different buttons outside that reveal the different widgets. Then use some custom signal for when the last button is activated to show a combobox that appears next to the last button.

Here is the link to the [QStackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)